# Why does the RASCAL IDE extension for Eclipse not work?

Tags: eclipse, menu, ide, rascal

I've tried to use this example of the RASCAL documentation: 
http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/util/IDE/Menus/Menus.html#/Rascal/Libraries/util/IDE/IDE.html

After registering the language and annotator nothing happens.

My goal is to build out this example to register some menu items for java files which could startup a RASCAL visualization or report.

Any help is appreciated.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Rascal console in Eclipse
2. type `import util::IDE;`
3. type `import ParseTree;`
4. type `m1 = popup(menu("MyMenu", [action("Example item", void (Tree t, loc s) { println("<t> @ <s>");})]));`
5. type `registerContributions("abc",{m1});`

I expect a new menu item 'MyMenu' in the Eclipse IDE when I open a *.abc file. I don't know where it should popup, the documentation doesn't tell where the menuitem should show up.

```html
rascal>import util::IDE;
ok
rascal>import ParseTree;
ok
rascal>m1 = popup(menu("MyMenu", [action("Example item", void (Tree t, loc s) { println("<t> @ <s>");})]));
Contribution: popup(menu(
    "MyMenu",
    [action("Example item",function(|prompt:///|(50,45,<1,50>,<1,95>)))]))
rascal>registerContributions("abc",{m1});
ok
rascal>registerContributions("rsc",{m1});
```

Comment: Could you add at the exact code you wrote and the UI actions you expected to work to your question? Currently it's rather vague 

Comment: I've added my steps to repoduce the problem to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a menu item to an editor which is not generated by Rascal itself but already exist in eclipse, for example a Java editor, you can use `registerNonRascalContributions`. See http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/util/IDE/IDE.html#/Rascal/Libraries/util/IDE/registerNonRascalContributions/registerNonRascalContributions.html

You need the "editor id" for the default Java editor plugin which is `org.eclipse.ui.JavaEditor` I believe.